# Missing operand after '2020.09' operator

Tags: c#, .net, dataview

I'm using this piece of code to filter out a `DataView` object but getting this exception. I checked the value of `dtExempt` in runtime so it's not a date format issue.

```
view.RowFilter = "'[resdate] >= '" + dtExempt.ToString( "yyyy.MM.dd" ) + "'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're surrounding the left hand side of the expression with single quotes, making it a string literal. Drop those quotes and you should be OK:

```
view.RowFilter = "[resdate] >= '" + dtExempt.ToString( "yyyy.MM.dd" ) + "'";
// Quote dropped--^
```